# Google Buzz return the status if the post submission was success or not?

Tags: api, google-buzz

Hi How can I know the status after the post submission? from my site i have made a google buzz buton when I click on this the defined post will submit to the google buzz url. but I want to know if the post submission was success of failure, because I need to keep a track on that. So that on next time I dont need to show the buzz icon there if I already posted there.

So how will I know it was a success or failure?

```
http://www.google.com/buzz/post?message=Here's%20Buzz!&url=http://www.google.com/buzz
```

or

```
window.open(
  "http://www.google.com/buzz/post?" +
  "message=Here's%20Buzz!&url=http://www.google.com/buzz",
  "_blank",
  "resizable=0,scrollbars=0,width=690,height=415"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either make an API call to search for the URL posted or you would need to subscribe to the Buzz Firehose to confirm that the post was created successfully.  The widget does not have a callback mechanism.

Alternatively, you could go through the OAuth 2 sequence, and instead of posting via the widget, post via the API.  Posting via the API will give you a response back telling you whether it succeeded or not.